# DOM element loads before the data is passed into the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory which makes a call to the API using AJAX like so

```
App.factory("DashboardData", function($q) {

method = 'POST';

var fetchDataFromApi = function(url, data) {
    code = null;
    response = null;

    return $.ajax({method: method, url: url, dataType: 'json', data: data}); };

return {

    counters: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return data = fetchDataFromApi('http://solmon.belgiumcampus.ac.za/api/data/getdashboarddata');}
};});
```

I then have a controller which calls to this factory and populates an array with the response that it receives like so

```
App.controller("DashboardWidgets", function($scope, DashboardData) {
var response = DashboardData.counters();

    $scope.CounterData = [];
response.then(function(response) {
    $scope.CounterData = [
        response.onlineUnits,
        response.offlineUnits,
        response.overallVoltage,
        response.overallCurrent,
        response.maintenanceUnits
    ];



});
alert("Online from controller: " + $scope.CounterData[0]);});
```

If I take out the alert at the end then the DOM element does not display the data that is received. Why is this happening and how would you recommend I fix it?

Comment: alert is called asynchronously. You should call the alert inside  then(function(){ //alert here}).

Comment: Are you using jQuery with Angular? Why not use $http service?